# statmodels regression plots not working with pandas datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.graphics as smg

data = pd.DataFrame({'Y': np.random.rand(1000), 'X':np.random.rand(1000)})
```

This works

```
smg.regressionplots.plot_fit(sm.OLS(data.Y.values, data.X.values).fit(), 0, y_true=None)
```

This doesn't

```
smg.regressionplots.plot_fit(sm.OLS(data.Y, data.X).fit(), 0, y_true=None)
smg.regressionplots.plot_fit(sm.OLS(data['Y'], data['X']).fit(), 0, y_true=None)
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I expected both to work. Is not working a bug or a usage issue?

Comment: Rather strange indeed, I think it's a bug. I know that simply doing linear regression (i.e. without plotting) works with pandas Series: `lm = sm.OLS(data['Y'], data['X']).fit();
lm.summary()` So it's kind of unexpected behaviour that plotting it using almost the same syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message reveals what's going on.  Condensing:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, **kwargs)

   6542                 start = xslice[0], y2slice[0]
-> 6543                 end = xslice[-1], y2slice[-1]

[...]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0.dev_fc8de6d-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)

    725         try:
--> 726             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    727         except KeyError, e1:
    728             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

[...]

KeyError: -1L
```

`data.X` and `data.Y` are `Series` objects, and you can't get the last element using `[-1]`.  If you could, then you could get yourself into trouble when you had an index which used `-1` as one of its elements: did you want the last element, or the one associated with `-1`?

`pandas` respected the "in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess" principle, and chose not to let this work, prioritizing labels over location.  You get a `KeyError`, not an `IndexError`, which hints at this.  See the discussion in the docs on [advanced indexing with integer labels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-integer-labels), for example.

Comment: +1 Makes sense and helps me proceed. But I would assume this would cause more than a few breaks as np.array(range(1,10))[-1] works. Is there some effort underway to address this?

Comment: :-(  Apparently I didn't explain it well enough.  A `Series` object is a fundamentally different kind of object than an `ndarray`.  In many ways, it's more like an ordered dict with some arraylike operations.  That's how you can get nice alignment on the indexes.  Certain operations which only require iteration will work on `Series`, but numeric indexing won't, in general.

Comment: [By "numeric indexing" I mean "position-based indexing."]

Comment: @DSM but the fact that `sm.OLS(data['Y'], data['X']).fit()` actually works shows that statsmodels supports pandas Series for regression (which, to me as a user, means that I don't need to know the internals of the indexing and such), but not the plotting of its result, which is kind of inconsistent, don't you think?

Comment: The explanation was sufficient. But my first thought was that libraries such as matplotlib will choose to maintain compatibility with ndarray over Series. For instance, in this example y2slice[-1]  will have to be replaced with something that would have to work for both ndarray and Series. Is there such an indexing?

Comment: @herrfz: I guess, but there are lots of datatypes which support iteration but not indexing.  Sets, for example, or dictionaries.  @user1827356: the only think I can think of that would work without requiring `matplotlib` to special-case things would be for it to convert its arguments to something it could index.  The real danger is that `data[-1]` will seem to work if `-1` happens to be the index, but it won't be the last one.  I can't see an easy way around that.

Answer (score 4):

I traced it out, it really is a bug in the `plot_fit` code. In the stable version you will find this line:

```
prstd, iv_l, iv_u = wls_prediction_std(results)
```

which returns `iv_l` and `iv_u`, presumably the upper and lower values for plotting the standard deviation of the fitted values, as pandas Series. This causes the subsequent call to `ax.fill_between` to fail.

This seems to have been fixed in the development version https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/graphics/regressionplots.py . There you will find a different call:

```
prstd, iv_l, iv_u = wls_prediction_std(results._results)
```

`iv_l` and `iv_u` are now numpy array and there should be no error anymore if you do:

```
smg.regressionplots.plot_fit(sm.OLS(data['Y'], data['X']).fit(), 0, y_true=None)
```

For now you'll just have to be satisfied with

```
smg.regressionplots.plot_fit(sm.OLS(data.Y.values, data.X.values).fit(), 0, y_true=None)
```

even though it's not really consistent with the usual call to standard linear regression.

Comment: As you pointed out, this should be fixed in master. Please file any bug reports on github, so we can have a look. http://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues

Comment: Sure, if you find it useful. I just thought that since it's fixed you're probably aware of the issue already...